# Wireless with 802.1x

Tags: arduino, wifi, router, radius

I have the following problem.

I'm trying to configure my router (Iskratel F50 or Mikrotik hAP lite) to control WiFi traffic with 802.1x and some kind of RADIUS server. But, when I configure everything on the router, and try to connect on that WiFi with my Android phone, it just refreshes the list of available wifi connections and shows the test connection as "saved". Nothing else happens.

If I'm right, the router should send UDP package, with access request data to RADIUS server or whatever it is on specified IP, right?

Can someone help me?

I need my device to get access request and then decide to allow or deny access to that client, depending on other details.

At the RADIUS IP is an Arduino device, that shows all data that came on RADIUS port to the LCD.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for a 802.1x-authentication over RADIUS, one would indeed expect to see several packets. The default ports for RADIUS are 1812/UDP (authentication) and 1813/UDP (accounting).

The first packet your router sends to the RADIUS IP should already have a User-Name-attribute. The connecting device should query the user for this. So, when you connected to that SSID, did your phone prompt you for a username (and password)?